# Multiple jobs on server using a script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jobs

I'm trying to automate sending many jobs to a server using the `qsub` command. I have made a shell script which creates multiple batch scripts based on some input files, using `printf`. The problem is these jobs don't run. When I open these batch scripts created from my shell script with gedit and save them without modifying them, they then work. This makes me think this is some kind of formatting issue.

Could you give me a solution to this issue?

Here's the shell script that creates the scripts to be submitted:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/PATH/

FILES=$(ls inpt/ | grep "centers")
i=1
declare -i i
for f in $FILES
do
    printf "#!/bin/bash\ncd /home/PATH/\n./nvt inpt/%b" "$f" > run-script$i.sh
    i=$i+1
done
```

Comment: Did you try a newline at the end?

Comment: No, I'll try that and tell you if it worked.

Comment: This worked Ignacio, thanks. Could you reply in the answer section so I mark the answer? Also for some reason, adding a new line at the end didn't give me a visible new line in the output script itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the executable bit to your scripts:

```
printf "#!/bin/bash\ncd /home/PATH/\n./nvt inpt/%b" "$f" > run-script$i.sh
chmod +x run-script$i.sh
```

To be sure that it is not a formting problem (or any problem with `printf`) you can try to use `echo`:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' > run-script$i.sh
echo cd /home/PATH/ >> run-script$i.sh
echo ./nvt "inpt/$f" >> run-script$i.sh
```

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't change anything. Only, saving it under gedit worked.

Comment: Could you please check all permissions?

Comment: Yes, it worked with echo too. I guess it must have been some kind of EOF problem.